# How do I check if a man page exists?

Tags: linux, bash, conditional-statements, manual

I'm trying to write a script to convert man pages to PDF files. The script I have right now is:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
[[ $# -ne 1 ]] && { echo "Usage: $(basename $0) [command]" ; exit 1 ; }
man -t ${1} | ps2pdf14 - > "${1}_man.pdf"
```

The problem is that if a man page does not exist, the script will still carry on executing, generating an empty PDF file. So I wonder if there's a way to determine if a man page exists?

Comment: Why not use troff/groff directly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Use Man's Exit Status from a Function

The man(1) manual page defines the following exit status codes:

> EXIT STATUS
>
> ```
> 0      Successful program execution.
> 1      Usage, syntax or configuration file error.
> 2      Operational error.
> 3      A child process returned a non-zero exit status.
> 16     At least one of the pages/files/keywords didn't exist or wasn't
>        matched.
> ```

That means you can use the exit status of *man* itself to determine if a page is available via *manpath*. For example:

```
check_for_man_page () {
    man "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1
}
```

With this function, you can use test conditionals on the exit status like so:

```
$ check_for_man_page "cat" && echo 'Found it!'
Found it!

$ check_for_man_page "quux" || echo 'Not found!'
Not found!
```

### Using an If/Else Statement

Here's another way to do this, using an if/else statement to determine whether to run your original code:

```
if man "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    man -t ${1} | ps2pdf14 - > "${1}_man.pdf"
else
    echo "Missing man page: $1" >&2
fi
```

Comment: For what it's worth, those specific exit status values may not apply on all platforms. My system returns exit status 1 for a missing man page.

Comment: @MichaelHoffman Doesn't matter. As long as it exits with a non-zero exit status, you know *something* went wrong. If *what* went wrong matters, then you can create a case statement or just report the exit status directly with **$?** instead.

Comment: It doesn't matter for this use case.

Comment: @CodeGnome Didn't know bash function will return last command's exit status.  Thanks for the function.

Answer (score 3):

It's not neat, but this seems to do what you want:

```
if man -w ${1} >/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
    man -t ${1} | ps2pdf14 - > "${1}_man.pdf"
fi
```

However, some man pages may exist in different sections of the manual -- for example `man 1 printf` and `man 3 printf`.  You may wish to modify your script to take this into account.